# Copy cell value and paste into another cell in same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set some automatic copy and paste solution to copy and paste value when I add something to google sheet. The idea would be to have 2 columns 'A' and 'B' where column A will contain price and can be adjusted, but column B should show original price.
I figured just copying the cell to another cell in the same row while it's getting added would do it.

Could you please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Ive found something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(sh.getName() == 'dados' && row > 1 && [2,3].includes(col)){
   sh.getRange(row,col+2).setValue(e.value);
  }
 }
```

But when I edit column number (i need just one col) it shows errors unfortunately

Syntax error: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token line: 7 file: macros.gs

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited the opening post with almost ideal solution, but I have issue adjusting it - when i try to remove this bit: && [2,3].includes(col)), it show syntax again.

Comment: I managed to use the code provided in OP, the one thing which is not matching my need is that if i edit column 1, column 2 is changing again, I would like to copy and paste just once and when source cell is changing, the destination cell will stay the same.

Comment: `function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(sh.getName() == 'Export' && row > 11)
  {
   sh.getRange(row,col+16).setValue(e.value);
  }` - this is how it looks now, but every edit is copied as well into column 16

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i think its not first language for us both :) What i try to do is to copy edited cell in column A to column B in the same row

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What i try to do is to copy edited cell in column A to column B in the same row`, for example, when the cell "C1" is edited, you want to put the value of "C1" to the cell "A1" and "B1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I mean: If C1 is edited, script should copy it to D1, if C3 is edited, script copy it to D3 and so on

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.